# VBA - error when trying to save file - Object doesn't support property or method?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run this code from a separate Excel file but I keep getting an on the xl.SaveAs line stating that the Object doesn't support the property or method. When I reference "xl." in the other sections such as the Refresh Table section, it works perfectly but not on the SaveAs method. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub DailyRefresh ()
    'Open and refresh Access
    Dim appAccess As Object
    Set appAccess = GetObject("S:\Shared\DailyRefresh.accdb")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    appAccess.Visible = True
    appAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro "Run_All_Queries"
    appAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase

   'Open Excel

    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks.Open ("s:\Shared\Template.xlsx")
    xl.Visible = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
'Set date to the 1st of the Month on Summary tab
    xl.Sheets("Summary").Visible = True
    xl.Sheets("Summary").Select
    xl.Range("C10").Value = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), 1)
    xl.Range("C10").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"

' REFRESH Table
    xl.Sheets("Data").Visible = True
    xl.Sheets("Data").Select
    xl.Range("A1").Select
    xl.Range("DailyRefresh.accdb[[#Headers],[ACTIVITY_DT]]").Select
    xl.Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    xl.Worksheets("Fname").Visible = True
    xl.Sheets("Fname").Select
    
     
'Copy and Save AS
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Path = "S:\Shared\NewTemplate"
    Filename = xl.Sheets("Fname").Range("A7").Value
    xl.SaveAs Path & Filename & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False
    xl.Worksheets("Fname").Visible = False
    xl.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be "Saving the document" - not "Saving the application" - in the case of Excel, the Document is the workbook.

For your "open" part, do it like this:

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("s:\Shared\Template.xlsx")
xl.Visible = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Then later, when you want to save the workbook, you just use the same `wb` variable:

```
wb.SaveAs Path & Filename & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False
wb.Close
xl.Quit
```

Comment: @Eyan Then consider accepting the answer (tick mark it) so that other visitor can know it solved.